# Is it possible to show a PopUp from a web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-applications, popup

Asp.Net 4.0

In my web applicaion i'm using web service methods. Is it possible to show a popup to request information from a user from a method in the web service?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: I suggest you to revise your knowledge regarding application architecture. A web service does not show or call a popup. Have a look at this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636689/difference-between-frontend-backend-and-middleware-in-web-development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636689/difference-between-frontend-backend-and-middleware-in-web-development)

Comment: I figured the web service is just a way to invoke webmethods that returned serialized data, was just wondering about the popup is all. I currently use modalpopupextender in code behind. I was trying to push off some of that to web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further details about the web service you are invoking, I will give you a quite general example. It requires jQuery.

It assumes that the web service is invoked by some trigger in the client: it could be a user event (click, key press) or a DOM event (load, ready). A handler is assigned to this event. In the case of a button-click event then:

```
$('#btnCallService').bind('click'
    , {dataObject: 'add evet related data here'}
    , function(event){
        /* here a handler is executed when btnCallService is clicked  */
        callServiceHandler(event.data)
    }
);
```

Here is the body of the handler, with the call to the service.

```
function callServiceHandler(eventData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url_to_your_service_method",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: yourWebMethodArguments,
        success: function (resultData) {
            /* everything is right! result data are available for client side processing and rendering */

            alert('Request completed!');
        }
        error: function (req, status, message) {
            /* something is wrong: guide the user */
            alert('Unable to execute your request: \n' + message);
        },

    });
}
```

As you can see, the web method calls no popup at all. You could centralize the handler in a library, and call it from every where in your site.

Comment: Ya, thats pretty much what I have now along with parsing the JSON for data results. I was just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use jQuery to call a function of web-service and you can show any popup

Comment: Im currently using jquery $ajax({ type: "POST" ..... and call my web method. not sure how to show the popup within the web method though.

Comment: according to ADC it is not possible

Comment: @tszoro it's not like opening a popup from web-service. It is about calling a service from jQuery and in the success function open a popup.

Comment: @tszoro how are you calling your web-service?

Comment: @Shekar I'm using jQuery $.ajax({ type: "POST"...etc.. I was just curious if there was an ajax method that could interupt code execution by sending data to client and then returning back to the code execution.

Answer (score 1):

you can call web methods using jquery, and based on the received data you can show msg box.
refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms) for better idea