# Allow the user to add only one event per cell over FullCalendar resource view

Tags: c#, jquery, html, mysql, asp.net

I am using FullCalendar Is there any way that ban the user to enter another event to the same day if s/he already added an event to that day before ?

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
public static void AllowEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, int Resource_id)
{
//using the startdate enddate and resourceid to pick the events already in that cell

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = EventDAO2.AllowEvents(start, end, user_id);
//get the eventid in dt.
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           //show a message"An event already exists in this cell"
        }
       //otherwise allow a popup window for entering event details,and add that values to the server.
}
```

Some mistakes,its not working correctly.i don't know how to show an alert message in c# code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `Select` operation on returned datatable to check whether your `eventid` already exist or not.

Something like that:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = EventDAO2.AllowEvents(start, end, user_id);

//get the eventid in dt.
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{        
    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("eventid=2 And user_id=" + user_id); //example

    if(drs.Length > 0) 
    {
         //show a message"An event already exists in this cell"
    }
    else
    {           
         //otherwise allow a popup window for entering event details,and add that values to the server.
    }
 }
 else
 {
    //otherwise allow a popup window for entering event details,and add that values to the server.
 }
```

You cannot show alert message from web service. However you could perform action based on the response received from web service.

You could track web method response using jquery, [here is helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505715/is-it-possible-to-show-a-popup-from-a-web-service).