# Import json file in node.js(Express) and export to index.jsx(React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to import a json file into my server.js file and then export it. And then import that exported data in my index.jsx file. I'm able to fetch the json data into my server.js file and also tried to export it using `export.modules` and `export default config` but I'm getting an error while I'm importing it in my index.jsx file.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\React Projects\SearchUI\node_modules\destroy'

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\React Projects\SearchUI\node_modules\send'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\React Projects\SearchUI\node_modules\express\lib
```

Following is the my code what i tried till now:
**server.js**

```
const confiq = require("../public/json/config.json");
module.exports = config;
```

**index.jsx**

```
import config from "../server/server";
console.log(config);
```

Comment: You are importing conf from "server", you have to export it in server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between frontend, backend, and middleware in web development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636689/difference-between-frontend-backend-and-middleware-in-web-development)

Comment: You are exporting confiq in server.js , it should be conf

Answer (score 1):

This should be :

```
// server.js
const confiq = require("../public/json/config.json");
module.exports = config; // exporting the config
```

```
// index.jsx

import confiq from "../server/server"; // importing the config
console.log(confiq);
```