# Why is the STL so heavily based on templates instead of inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, stl, std

I mean, aside from its name *the Standard Template Library* (which evolved into the C++ standard library).

C++ initially introduce OOP concepts into C. That is: you could tell what a specific entity could and couldn't do (regardless of how it does it) based on its class and class hierarchy. Some compositions of abilities are more difficult to describe in this manner due to the complexities of multiple inheritance, and the fact that C++ supports interface-only inheritance in a somewhat clumsy way (compared to java, etc), but it's there (and could be improved).

And then templates came into play, along with the STL. The STL seems to take the classical OOP concepts and flush them down the drain, using templates instead.

There should be a distinction between cases when templates are used to generalize types where the types themselves are irrelevant for the operation of the template (containers, for examples). Having a `vector<int>` makes perfect sense.

However, in many other cases (iterators and algorithms), templated types are supposed to follow a "concept" (Input Iterator, Forward Iterator, etc...) where the actual details of the concept are defined entirely by the implementation of the template function/class, and not by the class of the type used with the template, which is a somewhat anti-usage of OOP.

For example, you can tell the function:

```
void MyFunc(ForwardIterator<...> *I);
```

**Update:** As it was unclear in the original question, ForwardIterator is ok to be templated itself to allow any ForwardIterator type. The contrary is having ForwardIterator as a concept.

expects a Forward Iterator only by looking at its definition, where you'd need either to look at the implementation or the documentation for:

```
template <typename Type> void MyFunc(Type *I);
```

Two claims I can make in favor of using templates: 1. Compiled code can be made more efficient, by recompiling the template for each used type, instead of using dynamic dispatch (mostly via vtables). 2. And the fact that templates can be used with native types.

However, I am looking for a more profound reason for abandoning classic OOP in favor of templating for the STL?

Comment: You might to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-and-java-and-templates-in-c. The accepted answer is an excellent explanation of what templates offer you over generics.

Comment: "compiled code can be made more efficient, by tailor-compiling the template for each used type, instead of using vtables."  Yeah, but you get redundant code filling up the instruction cache.  In modern CPU architectures, you're typically constrained on (cache) memory rather than clock cycles.  But don't trust me: do the experiment.  Err, well, except that it takes reimplementing g++ ;-)

Comment: @Jonas: That doesn't make sense. The constraint on cache costs clock cycles, which is why it is important. At the end of the day, it is clock cycles, not cache, that defines performance. Memory, and cache is only important in so far as it affects the clock cycles spent. Moreover, the experiment can be done easily. Compare, say, std::for_Each called with a functor argument, with the equivalent OOP/vtable approach. The difference in performance is *staggering*. Which is why the template version is used.

Comment: and there is no reason why the redundant code would be filling up the icache. If I instantiate vector<char> and vector<int> in my program, why should the vector<char> code be loaded into icache while I'm processing the vector<int>? In fact, the code for vector<int> is trimmed because it doesn't have to include code for casting, vtables and indirection.

Comment: Alex Stepanov [explains](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/drdobbs-interview.html) why inheritance and equality don't play well together.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: @jalf: Uhm, close, but no. The constraint on cache costs *time*, which is subtly different to clock cycles. If you could double the clock rate you'd also double the number of stalled cycles when pulling a new cache line. Also, memory cycles spent pulling in new instructions are cycles not spent doing IO. This phenomenon is why sometimes code compiled with -Os is faster than the same code compiled with -O2. Sometimes you're using vector<char> and vector<int> at the same time - they might not both fit into the icache.

Comment: @BerndJendrissek: Uhm, close, but no yourself. Yes, more code costs in terms of memory bandwidth and cache usage **if it is ever actually used**. But there is no particular reason to expect a `vector<int>` and `vector<char>` to be used at the same time. They might, sure, but you might use *any* two pieces of code at the same time. That has nothing to do with templates, C++ or the STL. There is nothing in the instantiation of `vector<int>` which requires `vector<char>` code to be loaded or executed.

Comment: And for all practical purposes, time == clock cycles. Yes, different CPUs have different clock rates, but given any specific CPU, something which can be done in 1 cycle will always be faster than something which takes 2 cycles. Both are measures of time, they just use different units.

Answer (score 634, accepted):

The short answer is "because C++ has moved on". Yes, back in the late 70's, Stroustrup intended to create an upgraded C with OOP capabilities, but that is a long time ago. By the time the language was standardized in 1998, it was no longer an OOP language. It was a multi-paradigm language. It certainly had some support for OOP code, but it also had a turing-complete template language overlaid, it allowed compile-time metaprogramming, and people had discovered generic programming. Suddenly, OOP just didn't seem all that important. Not when we can write simpler, more concise *and* more efficient code by using techniques available through templates and generic programming.

OOP is not the holy grail. It's a cute idea, and it was quite an improvement over procedural languages back in the 70's when it was invented. But it's honestly not all it's cracked up to be. In many cases it is clumsy and verbose and it doesn't really promote reusable code or modularity.

That is why the C++ community is today far more interested in generic programming, and why *everyone* is finally starting to realize that functional programming is quite clever as well. OOP on its own just isn't a pretty sight.

Try drawing a dependency graph of a hypothetical "OOP-ified" STL. How many classes would have to know about each other? There would be a *lot* of dependencies. Would you be able to include just the `vector` header, without also getting `iterator` or even `iostream` pulled in? The STL makes this easy. A vector knows about the iterator type it defines, and that's all. The STL algorithms know *nothing*. They don't even need to include an iterator header, even though they all accept iterators as parameters. Which is more modular then?

The STL may not follow the rules of OOP as Java defines it, but doesn't it achieve the *goals* of OOP? Doesn't it achieve reusability, low coupling, modularity and encapsulation?

And doesn't it achieve these goals *better* than an OOP-ified version would?

As for why the STL was adopted into the language, several things happened that led to the STL.

First, templates were added to C++. They were added for much the same reason that generics were added to .NET. It seemed a good idea to be able to write stuff like "containers of a type T" without throwing away type safety. Of course, the implementation they settled on was quite a lot more complex and powerful.

Then people discovered that the template mechanism they had added was even more powerful than expected. And someone started experimenting with using templates to write a more generic library. One inspired by functional programming, and one which used all the new capabilities of C++.

He presented it to the C++ language committee, who took quite a while to grow used to it because it looked so strange and different, but ultimately realized that *it worked better than the traditional OOP equivalents they'd have to include otherwise*. So they made a few adjustments to it, and adopted it into the standard library.

It wasn't an ideological choice, it wasn't a political choice of "do we want to be OOP or not", but a very pragmatic one. They evaluated the library, and saw that it worked very well.

In any case, both of the reasons you mention for favoring the STL are absolutely essential.

The C++ standard library **has** to be efficient. If it is less efficient than, say, the equivalent hand-rolled C code, then people would not use it. That would lower productivity, increase the likelihood of bugs, and overall just be a bad idea.

And the STL **has** to work with primitive types, because primitive types are all you have in C, and they're a major part of both languages. If the STL did not work with native arrays, it would be **useless**.

Your question has a strong assumption that OOP is "best". I'm curious to hear why. You ask why they "abandoned classical OOP". I'm wondering why they should have stuck with it. Which advantages would it have had?

Comment: Good answer. I would add that templates depend on object oriented programming. Generic programming depends on being able to treat all types equally, whether intrinsic or user defined.

Comment: It's a good writeup, but I'd like to highlight one detail. The STL is not a "product" of C++. In fact, STL, as a concept, existed before C++, and C++ just happened to be an efficient language having (almost) enough power for generic programming, so STL was written in C++.

Comment: @Igor, i've given up telling people that "STL" is an ambiguous term :) STL seems to have become the de-facto name for all templates in the standard library nowadays

Comment: The STL in its entirety isn't in the standard library. slist and rope are two containers that aren't off the top of my head. I would also say that hash_set/map/multiset/multimap aren't, but 0x plans on fixing that (albeit with a stupid name. Yes I know why, it's still stupid)

Comment: Since comments keep bringing it up, yes, I'm aware that the STL name is ambiguous. But I can't think of a better name for "the part of the C++ standard library that is modelled on the STL". The  de-facto name for that part of the standard library *is* just "the STL", even though it is strictly inaccurate. :) As long as people don't use STL as the name for the *entire* standard library (including IOStreams and the C stdlib headers), I'm happy. :)

Comment: You failed to mention that STL was developed by Alexander Stepanov for Ada, and later on ported to C++ when the language got generics.

Comment: @PauloPinto that's because it (1) is irrelevant, and (2) is inaccurate. Stepanov worked on what would one day *become* the STL over a period of several years, and yes, he initially did this work in Ada. But that does not mean that the STL ever existed for Ada, and it was not "ported" to C++. The switch to C++ was much more than just a port, and it happened long before the library was complete (and before it had the STL name)

Comment: @jalf I remember reading about it in the "The C/C++ Users Journal" and "C++ Report" before C++ even got templates, maybe with age I got some facts wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with this answer! I was just referred to this question from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20829860/1593077), where I inquired about how to do something pretty basic in an OOP language: Expressing the fact that my class is a kind of set. Well, it turns out - I can't really do that, at least with the Standard Library. Of course this is just an example of a bigger issue. In my very humble opinion it seems to me that while C++ may be multi-paradigmatic, its standard library simply doesn't support Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: @einpoklum Your class is a set if it follows a certain protocol.

Comment: @FredOverflow: And in an OOP spirit, I would expect this protocol to be embodied in an interface (= abstract base class), so that certain functions or methods can take SetInterface& arguments.

Comment: @einpoklum And what exactly would you gain from an abstract base class? Take `std::set` as an example. It does not inherit from an abstract base class. How does that limit your usage of `std::set`? Is there anything you cannot do with a `std::set` because it does not inherit from an abstract base class?

Comment: @einpoklum please take a look at the Smalltalk language, which Alan Kay designed to be an OOP language when he invented the term OOP. It didn't have interfaces. OOP is not about interfaces or abstract base classes. Are you going to say that "Java, which is nothing like what the inventor of the term OOP had in mind is more OOP than C++ which *also* is nothing like what the inventor of the term OOP had in mind"? What you mean to say is "C++ is not Java-like enough for my taste". That is fair, but it has *nothing* to do with OOP.

Comment: @FredOverflow: It would let me write code which works on sets, abstractly; and I can (probably) share a lot more code; and I don't need to make source code visible between modules (unlike the case with templates). And there's probably more, but I'm not much of a language lawyer.

Comment: @einpoklum the source code that is being made visible between modules *is the standard library*. Your complaint is not "C++ doesn't allow me to use abstract base classes as interfaces" (because it does), but "the standard library does not define an abstract base class for sets". And so far you have not explained why that would be an advantage. You *can* write code which works on sets, abstractly.

Comment: That "someone" has a name: Alexander Stepanov. I think he deserves some recognition for his work.

Comment: -1 for writing a bunch of blatant nonsense and flat-out lies about OOP.  If it "didn't really promote reusable code or modularity", you wouldn't see literally millions of developers around the world re-using modules developed in OO languages.  If it didn't work, it wouldn't have taken over the world the way it has; such revisionist comments are sour-grapes nonsense from people who don't understand why *their* language, which is *clearly* so much better despite not having OO support, hasn't taken over the world. (See also: Paul Graham.)  Just because C++'s OOP sucks doesn't mean OOP sucks.

Comment: Right, it can't be bad if it's popular. So Coca Cola is healthy too, I assume? And Win32 is a well-designed API? You see literally millions of developers around the world reusing libraries developed in procedural languages and functional languages. Millions of developers using something proves nothing. As for sour grapes, have you looked in the mirror recently?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Those "OO languages" often do not use much OOP at all, or they are only now slowly discovering the power of functional and generic programming. Code does not become OOP when you put it into a class. Not in C++, not in Java, nor in C# or any other language I am aware of.

Comment: @MasonWheeler if this answer was a bunch a blatant nonsense you wouldn't see literally hundreds of developers around the world voting +1 on this with only three people doing otherwise

Comment: @panda-34: although that's of course just another argument in the way the author disregarded in one of his comments. Many upvotes reveal a consensus, not the truth. Still I'm among those +1 voters :-)

Comment: "Simpler and more concise"? Java beats C++ in conciseness hands-down. C++ is a monster. I was unpleasantly surprised when I picked it back up after a ten year long hiatus. What a joke of a language. :)

Comment: Most claims about OO here incorrectly assume that the only way to do OO is similar to the way that C++ did it. Other OO languages don't have C++'s limitations. For instance, "Would you be able to include just the vector header, without also getting iterator or even iostream pulled in?" first assumes that header files are the only way to share interfaces (they suck: textual inclusion hugely increases compile times.), and then assumes that sharing an entire iterator class or iostream class (instead of a tiny base class with only pure virtual methods, similar to a Java interface) would be needed.

Comment: The big adventage of OOP is invariant protection by means of public/private. It's an unvaluable resource and in my opinion its best feature. Inheritance and polymorphism are just ways of implementing data or behaviour reuse, without being the only ones.

Answer (score 92):

The most direct answer to what I think you're asking/complaining about is this: The assumption that C++ is an OOP language is a false assumption.

C++ is a multi-paradigm language. It can be programmed using OOP principles, it can be programmed procedurally, it can be programmed generically (templates), and with C++11 (formerly known as C++0x) some things can even be programmed functionally.

The designers of C++ see this as an advantage, so they would argue that constraining C++ to act like a purely OOP language when generic programming solves the problem better and, well, more *generically*, would be a step backwards.

Comment: "and with C++0x some things can even be programmed functionally" -- it can be programmed functionally without those features, just more verbosely.

Comment: @Tyler Indeed if you constrained C++ to pure OOP, you'd  be left with Objective-C.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry: Having just asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20829860/1593077), I find I've just uttered the same answer as you! Just one point. I wish you would add the fact that the Standard Library cannot be used to write Object-Oriented code.

Answer (score 81):

My understanding is that Stroustrup originally preferred an "OOP-styled" container design, and in fact didn't see any other way to do it.  Alexander Stepanov is the one responsible for the STL, and [his goals did not include "make it object oriented"](http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html):

> That is the fundamental point: algorithms are defined on algebraic structures. It took me another couple of years to realize that you have to extend the notion of structure by adding complexity requirements to regular axioms. ... I believe that iterator theories are as central to Computer Science as theories of rings or Banach spaces are central to Mathematics. Every time I would look at an algorithm I would try to find a structure on which it is defined. So what I wanted to do was to describe algorithms generically. That's what I like to do. I can spend a month working on a well known algorithm trying to find its generic representation. ...
>
> STL, at least for me, represents the only way programming is possible. It is, indeed, quite different from C++ programming as it was presented and still is presented in most textbooks. But, you see, I was not trying to program in C++, I was trying to find the right way to deal with software. ...
>
> I had many false starts. For example, I spent years trying to find some use for inheritance and virtuals, before I understood why that mechanism was fundamentally flawed and should not be used. I am very happy that nobody could see all the intermediate steps - most of them were very silly.

(He does explain why inheritance and virtuals -- a.k.a. object oriented design "was fundamentally flawed and should not be used" in the rest of the interview).

Once Stepanov presented his library to Stroustrup, Stroustrup and others went through herculean efforts to get it into the ISO C++ standard (same interview):

> The support of Bjarne Stroustrup was crucial. Bjarne really wanted STL in the standard and if Bjarne wants something, he gets it. ... He even forced me to make changes in STL that I would never make for anybody else ... he is the most single minded person I know. He gets things done. It took him a while to understand what STL was all about, but when he did, he was prepared to push it through. He also contributed to STL by standing up for the view that more than one way of programming was valid - against no end of flak and hype for more than a decade, and pursuing a combination of flexibility, efficiency, overloading, and type-safety in templates that made STL possible. I would like to state quite clearly that Bjarne is the preeminent language designer of my generation.

Comment: Interesting interview. Pretty sure I've read it before some time ago, but was definitely worth going through again. :)

Comment: One of the most interesting interviews about programming that I've ever read. Although it leaves me thirsting for more detail...

Comment: A lot of the complaints he makes about languages like Java ("You can't write a generic max() in Java that takes two arguments of some type and has a return value of that same type") were only relevant to very early versions of the language, before generics were added. Even from the beginning, it was known that generics would eventually be added added, though (once a viable syntax/semantics was figured out), so his criticisms are largely baseless. Yes, generics in some form are needed to preserve type safety in a statically typed language, but no, that does not make OO worthless.

Comment: @SomeGuy They're not complaints about Java per se. He's talking about "*the "standard" OO programming of SmallTalk or, say, Java*". The interview is from the late 90s (he mentions working at SGI, which he left in 2000 to work at AT&T). Generics were only added to Java in 2004 in version 1.5 and they are a deviation from the "standard" OO model.

Comment: If Stepanov got anything wrong, it would be making iterators first-class, instead of treating them as a building block for [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges).

Answer (score 27):

The answer is found in this [interview](http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html) with Stepanov, the author of the STL:

> Yes. STL is not object oriented. I
>   think that object orientedness is
>   almost as much of a hoax as Artificial
>   Intelligence. I have yet to see an
>   interesting piece of code that comes
>   from these OO people.

Comment: Nice gem; Do you know what year is it from?

Comment: @Kos, according to the https://web.archive.org/web/20000607205939/http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html the first version of the linked page is from June 7 2001. The page itself at the bottom says Copyright 2001-2008.

Comment: @Kos Stepanov mentions working at SGI in the first answer. He left SGI in May 2000, so presumably the interview is older than that.

Answer (score 21):

Why a pure OOP design to a Data Structure & Algorithms Library would be better ?!
OOP is not the solution for every thing.

IMHO, STL is the most elegant library I have seen ever :)

for your question,

you don't need runtime polymorphism, it is an advantage for STL actually to implement the Library using static polymorphism, that means efficiency.
Try to write a generic Sort or Distance or what ever algorithm that applies to ALL containers!
your Sort in Java would call functions that are dynamic through n-levels to be executed!

You need stupid thing like Boxing and Unboxing to hide nasty assumptions of the so called Pure OOP languages.

The only problem I see with STL, and templates in general is the awful error messages.
Which will be solved using Concepts in C++0X.

Comparing STL to Collections in Java is Like comparing Taj Mahal to my house :)

Comment: What, Taj Mahal is small and elegant, and your house is the size of a mountain, and a complete mess? ;)

Comment: Concepts aren't part of c++0x anymore. Some of the error messages can be pre-empted using `static_assert` perhaps.

Comment: GCC 4.6 has improved template error messages, and I believe that 4.7+ are even better with it.

Comment: A Concept is essentially the "interface" that the OP was asking for. The only difference is that "inheritance" from a Concept is implicit (if a class has all the right member functions, it is automatically a subtype of the Concept) rather than explicit (a Java class has to explicitly declare that it implements an interface). However, both implicit and explicit subtyping are valid OO, and some OO languages have implicit inheritance which works just like Concepts. So what is being said here is basically "OO sucks: use templates. But templates have problems, so use Concepts (which are OO)."

Answer (score 11):

> templated types are supposed to follow
>   a "concept" (Input Iterator, Forward
>   Iterator, etc...) where the actual
>   details of the concept are defined
>   entirely by the implementation of the
>   template function/class, and not by
>   the class of the type used with the
>   template, which is a somewhat
>   anti-usage of OOP.

I think you misunderstand the intended use of concepts by templates. Forward Iterator, for example, is a very well-defined concept. To find the expressions which must be valid in order for a class to be a Forward Iterator, and their semantics including computational complexity, you look at the standard or at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html (you have to follow the links to Input, Output, and Trivial Iterator to see it all).

That document is a perfectly good interface, and "the actual details of the concept" are defined right there. They are not defined by the implementations of Forward Iterators, and neither are they defined by the algorithms which use Forward Iterators.

The differences in how interfaces are handled between STL and Java are three-fold:

1) STL defines valid expressions using the object, whereas Java defines methods which must be callable on the object. Of course a valid expression might be a method (member function) call, but it doesn't have to be.

2) Java interfaces are runtime objects, whereas STL concepts are not visible at runtime even with RTTI.

3) If you fail to make valid the required valid expressions for an STL concept, you get an unspecified compilation error when you instantiate some template with the type. If you fail to implement a required method of a Java interface, you get a specific compilation error saying so.

This third part is if you like a kind of (compile-time) "duck typing": interfaces can be implicit. In Java, interfaces are somewhat explicit: a class "is" Iterable if and only if it *says* it implements Iterable. The compiler can check that the signatures of its methods are all present and correct, but the semantics are still implicit (i.e. they're either documented or not, but only more code (unit tests) can tell you whether the implementation is correct).

In C++, like in Python, both semantics and syntax are implicit, although in C++ (and in Python if you get the strong-typing preprocessor) you do get some help from the compiler. If a programmer requires Java-like explicit declaration of interfaces by the implementing class, then the standard approach is to use type traits (and multiple inheritance can prevent this being too verbose). What's lacking, compared with Java, is a single template which I can instantiate with my type, and which will compile if and only if all the required expressions are valid for my type. This would tell me whether I've implemented all the required bits, "before I use it". That's a convenience, but it's not the core of OOP (and it still doesn't test semantics, and code to test semantics would naturally also test the validity of the expressions in question).

STL may or may not be sufficiently OO for your taste, but it certainly separates interface cleanly from implementation. It does lack Java's ability to do reflection over interfaces, and it reports breaches of interface requirements differently.

> you can tell the function ...  expects a Forward Iterator only by
>   looking at its definition, where you'd need either to look at the 
>   implementation or the documentation for ...

Personally I think that implicit types are a strength, when used appropriately. The algorithm says what it does with its template parameters, and the implementer makes sure those things work: it's exactly the common denominator of what "interfaces" should do. Furthermore with STL, you're unlikely to be using, say, `std::copy` based on finding its forward declaration in a header file. Programmers *should* be working out what a function takes based on its documentation, not just on the function signature. This is true in C++, Python, or Java. There are limitations on what can be achieved with typing in any language, and trying to use typing to do something it doesn't do (check semantics) would be an error.

That said, STL algorithms usually name their template parameters in a way which makes it clear what concept is required. However this is to provide useful extra information in the first line of the documentation, not to make forward declarations more informative. There are more things you need to know than can be encapsulated in the types of the parameters, so you have to read the docs. (For example in algorithms which take an input range and an output iterator, chances are the output iterator needs enough "space" for a certain number of outputs based on the size of the input range and maybe the values therein. Try strongly typing that.)

Here's Bjarne on explicitly-declared interfaces: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cpp0xP.html

> In generics, an argument must be of a
>   class derived from an interface (the
>   C++ equivalent to interface is
>   abstract class) specified in the
>   definition of the generic. That means
>   that all generic argument types must
>   fit into a hierarchy. That imposes
>   unnecessary constraints on designs
>   requires unreasonable foresight on the
>   part of developers. For example, if
>   you write a generic and I define a
>   class, people can't use my class as an
>   argument to your generic unless I knew
>   about the interface you specified and
>   had derived my class from it. That's
>   rigid.

Looking at it the other way around, with duck typing you can implement an interface without knowing that the interface exists. Or someone can write an interface deliberately such that your class implements it, having consulted your docs to see that they don't ask for anything you don't already do. That's flexible.

Comment: On explicitly declared interfaces, two words: type classes. (Which are already what Stepanov means by "concept".)

Comment: "If you fail to make valid the required valid expressions for an STL concept, you get an unspecified compilation error when you instantiate some template with the type." -- that is false.  Passing in something to the `std` library that fails to match a concept is usually "ill-formed, no diagnostic required".

Comment: True, I was playing fast and loose with the term "valid". I just meant if the compiler can't compile one of the required expressions, then it will report something.

Answer (score 8):

"OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things. It can be done in Smalltalk and in LISP. There are possibly other systems in which this is possible, but I'm not aware of them." - Alan Kay, creator of Smalltalk.

C++, Java, and most other languages are all pretty far from classical OOP.  That said, arguing for ideologies is not terribly productive.  C++ is not pure in any sense, so it implements functionality that seems to make pragmatic sense at the time.

Answer (score 8):

STL started off with the intention of provide a large library covering most commonly used algorithm -- with the target of consitent behavior and **performance**. Template came as a key factor to make that implementation and target feasible.

Just to provide another reference:

Al Stevens Interviews Alex Stepanov, in March 1995 of DDJ:

- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/drdobbs-interview.html

Stepanov explained his work experience and choice made towards a large library of algorithm, which eventually evolved into STL.

> **Tell us something about your long-term interest in generic programming**
>
> .....Then I was offered a job at Bell Laboratories working in the C++ group on C++ libraries. They asked me whether I could do it in C++. Of course, I didn't know C++ and, of course, I said I could. But I couldn't do it in C++, because in 1987 C++ didn't have templates, which are essential for enabling this style of programming. Inheritance was the only mechanism to obtain genericity and it was not sufficient.
>
> Even now C++ inheritance is not of much use for generic programming. Let's discuss why. Many people have attempted to use inheritance to implement data structures and container classes. As we know now, there were few if any successful attempts. C++ inheritance, and the programming style associated with it are dramatically limited. It is impossible to implement a design which includes as trivial a thing as equality using it. If you start with a base class X at the root of your hierarchy and define a virtual equality operator on this class which takes an argument of the type X, then derive class Y from class X. What is the interface of the equality? It has equality which compares Y with X. Using animals as an example (OO people love animals), define mammal and derive giraffe from mammal. Then define a member function mate, where animal mates with animal and returns an animal. Then you derive giraffe from animal and, of course, it has a function mate where giraffe mates with animal and returns an animal. It's definitely not what you want. While mating may not be very important for C++ programmers, equality is. I do not know a single algorithm where equality of some kind is not used.

Answer (score 5):

The basic problem with

```
void MyFunc(ForwardIterator *I);
```

is how do you safely get the type of the thing the iterator returns? With templates, this is done for you at compile time.

Comment: Well, I either: 1. Don't try to get it, since I'm writing generic code. Or, 2. Get it using whatever reflection mechanism C++ offers these days.

Answer (score 3):

For a moment, let's think of the standard library as basically a database of collections and algorithms.

If you've studied the history of databases, you undoubtedly know that back in the beginning, databases were mostly "hierarchical". Hierarchical databases corresponded very closely to classical OOP--specifically, the single-inheritance variety, such as used by Smalltalk.

Over time, it became apparent that hierarchical databases could be used to model almost anything, *but* in some cases the single-inheritance model was fairly limiting. If you had a wooden door, it was handy to be able to look at it either as a door, or as a piece of some raw material (steel, wood, etc.)

So, they invented network model databases. Network model databases correspond very closely to multiple inheritance. C++ supports multiple inheritance completely, while Java supports a limited form (you can inherit from only one class, but can also implement as many interfaces as you like).

Both hierarchical model and network model databases have mostly faded from general purpose use (though a few remain in fairly specific niches). For most purposes, they've been replaced by relational databases.

Much of the reason relational databases took over was versatility. The relational model is functionally a superset of the network model (which is, in turn, a superset of the hierarchical model).

C++ has largely followed the same path. The correspondence between single inheritance and the hierarchical model and between multiple inheritance and the network model are fairly obvious. The correspondence between C++ templates and the hierarchical model may be less obvious, but it's a pretty close fit anyway.

I haven't seen a formal proof of it, but I believe the capabilities of templates are a superset of those provided by multiple inheritance (which is clearly a superset of single inerhitance). The one tricky part is that templates are mostly statically bound--that is, all the binding happens at compile time, not run time. As such, a formal proof that inheritance provides a superset of the capabilities of inheritance may well be somewhat difficult and complex (or may even be impossible).

In any case, I think that's most of the real reason C++ doesn't use inheritance for its containers--there's no  real reason to do so, because inheritance provides only a subset of the capabilities provided by templates. Since templates are basically a necessity in some cases, they might as well be used nearly everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This question has many great answers. It should also be mentioned that templates supports an open design. With the current state of object oriented programming languages, one has to use the visitor pattern when dealing with such problems, and true OOP should support multiple dynamic binding. See [Open Multi-Methods for C++, P. Pirkelbauer, et.al.](http://www.stroustrup.com/multimethods.pdf) for very intersting reading.

Another interesting point of templates are that they can be used on for runtime polymorphism as well. For example

```
template<class Value,class T>
Value euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,Value y_0,const T& func)
    {
    auto dt=(t_end-t_0)/N;
    for(size_t k=0;k<N;++k)
        {y_0+=func(t_0 + k*dt,y_0)*dt;}
    return y_0;
    }
```

Notice that this function will also work if `Value` is a vector of some kind (*not* std::vector, which should be called `std::dynamic_array` to avoid confusion)

If `func` is small, this function will gain a lot from inlining. Example usage

```
auto result=euler_fwd(10000,0.0,1.0,1.0,[](double x,double y)
    {return y;});
```

In this case, you should know the exact answer (2.718...), but it is easy to construct a simple ODE without elementary solution (Hint: use a polynomial in y).

Now, you have a large expression in `func`, and you use the ODE solver in many places, so your executable gets polluted with template instantiations everywhere. What to do? First thing to notice is that a regular function pointer works. Then you want to add currying so you write an interface and an explicit instantiation

```
class OdeFunction
    {
    public:
        virtual double operator()(double t,double y) const=0;
    };

template
double euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,double y_0,const OdeFunction& func);
```

But the above instantiation only works for `double`, why not write the interface as template:

```
template<class Value=double>
class OdeFunction
    {
    public:
        virtual Value operator()(double t,const Value& y) const=0;
    };
```

and specialize for some common value types:

```
template double euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,double y_0,const OdeFunction<double>& func);

template vec4_t<double> euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,vec4_t<double> y_0,const OdeFunction< vec4_t<double> >& func); // (Native AVX vector with four components)

template vec8_t<float> euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,vec8_t<float> y_0,const OdeFunction< vec8_t<float> >& func); // (Native AVX vector with 8 components)

template Vector<double> euler_fwd(size_t N,double t_0,double t_end,Vector<double> y_0,const OdeFunction< Vector<double> >& func); // (A N-dimensional real vector, *not* `std::vector`, see above)
```

If the function had been designed around an interface first, then you would have been forced to inherit from that ABC. Now you have this option, as well as function pointer, lambda, or any other function object. The key here is that we must have `operator()()`, and we must be able to do use some arithmetic operators on its return type. Thus, the template machinery would break in this case if C++ did not have operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

How do you do comparisons with ForwardIterator*'s?  That is, how do you check if the item you have is what you're looking for, or you've passed it by?

Most of the time, I would use something like this:

```
void MyFunc(ForwardIterator<MyType>& i)
```

which means I know that i is pointing to MyType's, and I know how to compare those.  Though it looks like a template, it isn't really (no "template" keyword).

Comment: you can just use the <, > and = operators of the type and not know what those are (though this might not be what you meant)

Comment: Depending on the context, those may not make any sense, or they may work fine.  Hard to tell without knowing more about MyType, which, presumable, the user does, and we don't.

Answer (score -1):

The concept of separating interface from interface and being able to swap out the implementations is not intrinsic to Object-Oriented Programming. I believe it's an idea that was hatched in Component-Based Development like Microsoft COM. (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/991517#991517) on What is Component-Driven Development?) Growing up and learning C++, people were hyped out inheritance and polymorphism. It wasn't until 90s people started to say "Program to an 'interface', not an 'implementation'" and "Favor 'object composition' over 'class inheritance'." (both of which quoted from GoF by the way).

Then Java came along with built-in garbage collector and `interface` keyword, and all of a sudden it became practical to actually separate interface and implementation. Before you know it the idea became part of the OO. C++, templates, and STL predates all of this.

Comment: Agreed that interfaces are not just OO.  But the ability polymorphism in the type system is (it was in Simula in the 60s).  Module interfaces existed in Modula-2 and Ada, but these operated in the type system differently I think.