# Problems with inheritance in the STL

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

In http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf, Alexander Stepanov mentions:

> It is interesting to note that the only examples of inheritance that
>   remained in STL inherit from empty classes. Originally, there were
>   many uses of inheritance inside the containers and even iterators, but
>   they had to be removed because of the problems they caused.

What are the technical problems that precluded the use of inheritance in the STL?

Comment: I imagine it may have had to do with the way that the STL deals with orthogonal concepts that are not easily expressed via inheritance.

Comment: This talk is really interesting and may also offer some illumination: https://youtu.be/COuHLky7E2Q

Comment: @caps Thanks. Looks like an interesting talk. I enjoy this guy's stuff.

Comment: @caps I've been playing with reimplementing some of the fundamental stuff from the standard library, and I originally had used inheritance for my pector-inspired vector. It inherited from a range-like type in order to separate the concept of an object array from the concept of an object array with associated dynamic memory. I think it fits semantically quite well, but it has some space-optimization problems for pector-like short vectors compared to emulating inheritance by defining a cast to my range object. So it got me curious where else was inheritance tried and why it failed.

Comment: Often people use inheritance to define interfaces and constraints. One of the problems you may frequently encounter when doing this is that child classes don't necessarily have all the same conceptual constraints and/or interfaces as their parent classes.

Comment: @caps I think it was a very good talk indeed (even with the pronunciation and sound quality). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the paper. I read it and watch the talk and they are both interesting. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer to your quesiton in it and I also wonder what are exactly the issues he's talking about.

There are multiple points (usually critics around rejections or modifications of propositions for the STL) in his paper where I would have liked more details on why he stated something which is strange considering the other part are often very detailed. Maybe we should ask him the question ! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I will put some comments directly from Alexander Stepanov (http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html).

> **Question:**
>
> STL is full of creative uses of templates, such as symbolic
>   types exported from classes, or the pattern matching of a set of
>   overloaded algorithms onto iterator tags. Surely enough, no standard
>   C++ Programming book speaks about those idioms. How did you come to
>   these C++ code idioms?
>
> **Answer:**
>
> I knew exactly what I was trying to accomplish. So I tweaked
>   the language until I was able to get by. But it took me many years to
>   discover all the techniques. And I had many false starts. For example,
>   I spent years trying to find some use for inheritance and virtuals,
>   before I understood why that mechanism was fundamentally flawed and
>   should not be used. I am very happy that nobody could see all the
>   intermediate steps - most of them were very silly. It takes me years
>   to come up with anything half decent. It also helped that Bjarne was
>   willing to put certain features in the language just to enable some of
>   my idioms. He once refered to it as "just in time language design."

Next, I will allow myself to direct you to this great answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1039904/210971

> OOP is not the holy grail. It's a cute idea, and it was quite an
>   improvement over procedural languages back in the 70's when it was
>   invented. But it's honestly not all it's cracked up to be. In many
>   cases it is clumsy and verbose and it doesn't really promote reusable
>   code or modularity.
>
> That is why the C++ community is today far more interested in generic
>   programming, and why everyone are finally starting to realize that
>   functional programming is quite clever as well. OOP on its own just
>   isn't a pretty sight.

And now something from me:

OOP rules dictates the way (inheritance, polymorphism, etc.) a programmer thinks about interaction between things (objects, entities, tribbles, etc.).

This is clearly visible in this simple Java example from time before adding support for generics (but these are not as verbose as in C++).

```
List v = new ArrayList();
v.add("test");
Integer i = (Integer)v.get(0); // Run time error
```

Although the code is compiled without error, it throws a runtime exception (java.lang.ClassCastException) when executing the third line of code. This type of problem can be avoided by using generics and is the primary motivation for using generics.

```
List<String> v = new ArrayList<>();
v.add("test");
Integer i = v.get(0); // (type error)  compilation-time error
```

Alexander Stepanov recognized that generic approach can solve this issue, help in providing logical separation (abstraction) between data structures and algorithms. This is why there is so much emphasis on iterators, functors, and many other idioms that fit very well into generic world.