# How to make code modular?

Tags: java, module, osgi, modularity

I have some Java programs, now I want to find out whether it is modular or not, if it is modular then up to what extent, because modularity can never be binary term i.e. 0 or 1. 
How do I decide that particular code is modular upto this much extent. I want to know how to make code much more modular?

Comment: If code is truly modular, each component should be a black box. The less knowledge components know about each other, the more modular the system.

Answer (score 48):

**Some Benchmarks for modularity:**

1. How many times are you **[rewriting similar code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)** for doing a particular task?
2. How much do you have to **[refactor your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)** when you change some part of your program?
3. Are the files **small and easy** to navigate through?
4. Are the [application modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) performing adequately and independently as and when required?
5. Is your code **minimally disastrous**? Does all hell break lose when you delete just one function or variable? **Do you get 20-odd errors upon re-naming a class?** (To examine this, you can implement a **stacking mechanism** to keep trace of all the hops in your application)
6. How near is the code to **natural language usage?** (i.e. modules and their subcomponents represent more real world objects without giving much concern to net source file size).

For more ideas check out [this blurb about modularity](http://web.archive.org/web/20090323235054/http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/courseware/cse2304/hndtC.html) and this one on [software quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_quality)

As for your concern on **making your code more modular** first you should ask yourself the above questions, obtain specific answers for them and then have a look at [this](http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/courses/cpm/notes/progreq/node2.html).

The **basic philosophy** is to break down your application into as small of code fragments as possible, arranged neatly across a multitude of easily understandable and accessible directory layouts.

Each method in your application **must do no more than the minimum quanta of processing needed**. Combining these methods into more and more macro level methods should lead you back to your application.

Comment: Another benchmark might be the "deletion criterion": If you delete X (package, class, method, field) from your program, what breaks? If there are breaks, how "far away" are they from the deleted item? If  the broken items are distant, then that means X was less modular.

Comment: (Add to previous comment) - When you delete something, you immediately expose its connections with the rest of the program - all of the places where it is wired to calling code. More modularity *usually* means fewer connection points, and usually means the connection points are more "local" in scope (for instance, within a single package).

Comment: altough it does get taken care of partly in refactoring and partly in independent testing of modules, still no harm in mentioning it separately!

Comment: The "check this out" link is broken, unfortunately.

Answer (score 27):

Key points are

- Separation of concerns
- Cohesion
- Encapsulation (communicates via interface)
- Substitutability
- Reusability

A good example of such module system is standard car parts like disk brakes and car stereo.
You don't want to build car stereo from scratch when you are building cars. You'd rather buy it and plug it in. You also don't want the braking system affecting the car stereo — or worse car stereo affecting the brake system.

To answer your question, "How do I decide that particular code is modular up to this much extent," we can form questions to test the modularity. **Can you easily substitute your modules with something else without affecting other parts of your application?**

XML parsers could be another example. Once you obtain the DOM interface, you really don't care which implementation of XML parser is used underneath (e.g. Apache Xerces or JAXP).

In Java, another question may be: **Are all functionality accessible via `interface`s?** Interface pretty much takes care of the low coupling.

Also, **can you describe each module in your system with one sentence?** For example, a car stereo plays music and radio. Disk brakes decelerate the vehicle safely.

---

(Here's what I wrote to [What is component driven development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/991517#991517))

According to Wikipedia, Component-Based Development is an alias for [Component-based software engineering (CBSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering).

> [It] is a branch of software
> engineering, the priority of which is
> the *separation of concerns* in respect
> of the wide-ranging functionality
> available throughout a given software
> system.

This is somewhat vague, so let's look at more details.

> An individual component is a software
> package, or a module, that
> encapsulates a set of related
> functions (or data).
>
> All system processes are placed into
> separate components so that all of the
> data and functions inside each
> component are semantically related
> (just as with the contents of
> classes). Because of this principle,
> it is often said that components are
> *modular* and *cohesive*.

So, according to this definition, a component can be anything as long as it does one thing really well and only one thing.

> With regards to system-wide
> co-ordination, components communicate
> with each other via *interfaces*. [...]
> This principle results in components referred to as *encapsulated*.

So this is sounding more and more like what we think of good API or SOA should look like.

The *provided* interfaces are represented by a lollipop and *required* interfaces are represented by an open socket symbol attached to the outer edge of the component in UML.

[image]

> Another important attribute of
> components is that they are
> *substitutable*, so that a component
> could be replaced by another (at
> design time or run-time), if the
> requirements of the initial component
> (expressed via the interfaces) are met
> by the successor component.
>
> Reusability is an important
> characteristic of a high quality
> software component. A software
> component should be designed and
> implemented so that it can be reused
> in many different programs.

Substitutability and reusability is what makes a component a component.
So what's the difference between this and Object-Oriented Programming?

> The idea in object-oriented
> programming (OOP) is that software
> should be written according to a
> mental model of the actual or imagined
> objects it represents. [...]
>
> Component-based software engineering,
> by contrast, makes no such
> assumptions, and instead states that
> software should be developed by gluing
> prefabricated components together much
> like in the field of electronics or
> mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your specific question of **how to make** the code more modular, a couple of approaches are:

- One of best tool for modularization is spotting code re-use. If you find that your code does the same exact (or very similar) thing in more than once place, it's a good candidate for modularizing away.
- Determine which pieces of logic can be made independent, in a sense that other logic would use them without needing to know how they are built. This is somewhat similar to what you to in OO design, although module/component does not necessarily need to correspond to a modeled object as in OO.

Answer (score 2):

Hej,

See, "How to encapsulate software (Part 1)," here:

http://www.edmundkirwan.com/encap/overview/paper7.html

Regards,

Ed.

Answer (score 1):

Since this has been tagged with 'osgi', I can throw in an OSGi-related perspective.

The short answer is that it is possible to go from completely spaghetti code to modular in small steps; it doesn't have to be a big bang. For example, even spaghetti code depends on some kind of bolognaise logging library, so in some sense, it's already modular, just with One Very Big Metball (sorry, module) in it.

The trick is to break the big meatball into one smaller chunk and then a slightly less big meatball and then recurse. It doesn't all have to be done in one go either; simply chip off a bit more each time until there is nothing left to remove.

As for OSGi, it's still possible to put an uber-jar into a bundle. In fact, you can do this without changing the bits; either by modifying the Manifest.MF in place, or by wrapping that in another JAR and specify Bundle-ClassPath: metaball.jar in the manifest.

Failing that, tools like BND can help generate the right data you'd need, and then it can be dropped in an OSGi runtime easily enough. But beware of overly coupled code, and stuff that mucks around with classloaders - those will trip you up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, that you want to know what it is that makes code modular, since code modules will obviously need some dependency between each other to work at all. This is my answer:

If you can break your system down into modules, and you can test those modules in isolation, that is a good indication that a system is modular.

Answer (score 0):

As you say modularity is not a binary thing so it depends on your relative definition.

I would say: Can you use a given method in any program where you need to perform that function?  Is it the "black box" where you wouldn't need to know what it were doing under the hood?  If the answer is no, i.e. the method would only work properly in that program then it is not truely modular.

Answer (score 0):

Modularity is relative to who ever is developing the code. But I think the general consensus is that modular code is code that has portions that can easily be swapped out without changing most of the original code.

IMHO, If you have 3 modules A B and C and you want to change or replace module C completely, if it is a SIMPLE task to do so then you have modular code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code analysis tool such as [CAP](http://cap.xore.de/) to analyse the dependencies between types and packages. They'll help you find and remove any cyclic dependencies, which are often a problem when trying to develop modular code.
If there are no cyclic dependencies, you can start separating your code into discrete jars.

In general it is good practice to code to interfaces if you can, this generally means your code can more easily be refactored and/or used in different contexts.

Dependency injection frameworks such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) can also help with the modularity of your design. As types are injected with their dependencies by some external configuration process they don't need a direct dependency on an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [package-by-feature](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) idea helps to make code more modular.

Many examples seen on the web divide applications first into layers, not features

- models
- data access
- user interface

It seems better, however, to divide applications up using top-level packages that align with **features, not layers**.

Here is an [example](http://www.web4j.com/predict/javadoc/index.html) of a web app that uses package-by-feature. Note the names of the top-level packages, which read as a list of actual features in the application. Note as well how each package contains all items related to a feature - the items aren't spread out all over the place; most of the time, they are all in a single package/directory.

Usually, deletion of a feature in such an app can be implemented in a single operation - deletion of a single directory.