# sharing features or not in git flow?

Tags: git, github, workflow, git-flow

In development, we often come across a scenario like this:

In a MVC web development, stuff A may mainly develop View, while stuff B may mainly develop Controller, then a feature branch like `feature/account` maybe shared by A and B to cooperate the development of account.

If we manage feature branches like above:

Question 1: Is it recommended that sharing feature branches between stuffs between stuffs?

There's another way to manage feature branches, like this:

- stuff A manage a branch named `feature/account-view`
- stuff B manage a branch named `feature/account-controller`

However, If we manage feature branches like `account-view` and `account-controller`, we need to merge these two feature branches first before doing some testing jobs. And it seems the workflow becomes more complicated.

Question 2: Which branch management is better? `feature/account` or `feature/account-view` `feature/account-controller`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it recommended that sharing feature branches between stuffs?

Yes, that is what a configuration is:

Generally, `feature/account-controller` is more practical, and closer to a *configuration* management: your branch represents the configuration you need to work.
If `stuffA` and `stuffB` are in their own Git repos, then it is a [component approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322295/6309), where you use one branch to isolate evolutions done on a set of components (group of files, here `stuffA` and `stuffB`, your config) you need to develop and test.

Comment: I try to catch your meaning. Do you mean that we should take `feature/account-controller` as one component?

Comment: @Charles0429 no, unless stuffA and stuffB are in the same repo. A "component" (coherent set of file) usually is a all Git repo. Anyway, the idea is to use the same branch for StuffA and StuffB.

Comment: @Charles0429 by the way, are StuffA and StuffB 2 different Git repos, or 2 folders within 1 repo?

Comment: stuffA and stuffB works in the same git repos, stuffA focus on frontend programming and stuffB focus on backend programming. But at the same time, they should cooperate to finish a function(ie user account management in a web system). So, when we need do some testing, we need to merge the two branches if we manange branch like `account-controller`, so I think it's not very convenient at the time of testing. If we manage branch like `account`, stuffA and stuffB share the branch, then they may affect each other, so I ask this question to find a better solution. Please give me some advice~

Comment: @Charles0429 If they are in the same repo, one branch is enough for both components, especially if they are linked (meaning changing one usually involves changing the other)