# Integrating RTC and Worklight, SCM Strategies

Tags: version-control, ibm-mobilefirst, rational-team-concert

Is there any best practice for dividing a worklight project into streams and components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [IBM Worklight project](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight-foundation) should use components for each **coherent set of files**, like a worklight project (with its containers, html files, css, ...)

Anything generated, like an android project generated to be run and simulated, shouldn't be in a component.

You can start simple with a single stream (which groups all components you need to work), or with one stream per component (but that approach doesn't scale well past 10-20 components, since the streams have no hierarchy)

Comment: @IdanAdar no, coherent set of fileS, as in "multiple files".

Comment: I'm a little unsure about the coherent set of files part. Lets say that I have a hybrid app with 2 adapters and a common folder a ipad and a android environments. Should I have a component for each adapter folder, etc... Or should I create a worklight project for each adapter, etc and put all of that in one component under a (1) stream?

Comment: @Silva "coherent" means it has its own history: if one adapter can evolve while the other is unchanged, *and* one adapter is more than a few files, then it is a good candidate for a component. And yes, the stream is where you add all the components you need to work.

Comment: As an example, if I understood you right, I should put inside one component every file needed for a adapter compilation and deployment. Is this a good approach? I'm sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: @Silva yes, it is a good approach, and part of a component approach (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7322295/6309).

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your answers. It has helped me grasp the RTC vs worklight problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Silva,

Perhaps the following IBM Worklight user documentation topic will help you: [Integrating with source control systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html?lang=en).

There is [the following approach](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_source_code_management_with_worklight_subversion?lang=en) as well.