# Should I create a Git repo in project source folder or at upper level

Tags: git

Should I create a Git repo in project source folder or at upper level?

e.g.

Method 1

```
.git
project
project\foo.c
project\bar.c
```

Method 2 (under project folder)

```
.git 
foo.c
bar.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one. However, some people prefer to put sources in `src` directory. It is useful when your project gets more complex and you have to include docs, tests (you would put them in project directory, right next to `src`).

Answer (score 4):

The goal of versioning a project is to get back (from any state of its history), an operational state able to **reproduce** what you were doing with said project.

So if you can copy a specific directory and still get back a fully functioning project (whatever that project is), use that as a criteria to create your `.git` within that directory.

Comment: +1 for trying to put some reasoning in there. There would be situations in which to decompose your projects into separate repositories, but I'll save that for another day; let the OP learn a bit :)

Comment: @sehe: you mean "system approach" vs. "component approach" (with git submodules)? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769941)? Right, this is for level 2 ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897157 as an intro, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933735 for a general context, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245224 for a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

Why my git lives in the parent of src/ folder;

1) There are important files I want in my repo that do not belong in src/. This includes the README.md files for my git repo, license files, any supporting project documentation etc.

2) Keeping supporting files AND my src folder at the git root level makes it easier for the users to quickly see where my source code is (in src obviously) versus supporting documents and folders. Otherwise they have to hunt and guess.

3) I often use my console to manually compile and execute code (because nerd), as well as manage git. I find it much easier to do this when my working folder is the parent of src/ (becuase I need fewer path related options). However, if my git was in src/ I would have to change working directories to run my git commands.

4) I often keep a docker instance of my project, and am constantly messing around with it. The Docker file sits in the parent of source, so again, less path related options to type.

Why my git I sometimes (but rarely) lives in src/

1) When a repo is all code and nothing else (usually when using it as a reference), the src folder just adds more resistance than value.

2) When the parent of source is a big cluttered mess of stuff, or you find it to much work to .gitignore your IDE project file and execution folder. My folders are never a mess, and .gitgnore isn't that hard, so reason (1) is pretty much my only reason.

There is no wrong way, and the right way is just what suits your style or project needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your Git repository at the deepest possible level that is a parent of the files and directories you want to manage with Git.

So, in your example, it would be method 2.