# Checkout a GitHub project to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, egit, mylyn, vcs-checkout

I need to checkout on my Eclipse Workspace an existing project hosted on GitHub. I have the project URL, and I already installed Egit and Mylyn. But I don't know what the next step is. Could you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396349/eclipse-egit-clone-project-into-workspace?rq=1

Comment: Here's a tutorial on Egit: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have mylyn and egit, then you may also want to install the [github connector](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github_mylyn). Afterwards you can directly import a github repository just giving the name (see the second screenshot of the link).

Comment: Doing this, the repository is added to the "Git Repositories" view. Now, how can I import it as a (Maven/Ant/Eclipse) project into Eclipse in order to work with the project(s) hosted within this Github repository?

Comment: Right click on the repository -> "Import projects".

Comment: Scenario: this repository hosts a Maven project (`pom.xml`) and I want to import it as a project into Eclipse. Solution: Right click repository -> "Import Projects..." -> "Import as general project" -> "Finish". Now right-click the newly created project -> "Configure" -> "Convert to Maven Project". Now right-click project and select "Run As..." -> "Maven Build..." for building options .......... is there any less awkward solution?

Comment: For a Maven project the most easy way is Import -> Maven -> Materialize from SCM, without any of the above steps. And please create your own questions for unrelated questions. This will totally confuse further readers.

Comment: I'm sorry for hurting your feelings. I read the question ass importing a project, not (only) about importing a repository.