# How to clone a git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to clone this project:

https://github.com/Guemache/StatisticsSquad/tree/master/ProjetWeb

I tried to do this with eclipse, but without success.

How to clone the repository?

Comment: what do you mean by open? are you asking how to use `git clone`?

Comment: @nikis i'm beginner so i don't know how to use git clone. I want just to run and test this project on eclipse

Comment: Usually you would use Git to clone the project on your local computer. Then you open that local project in Eclipse. If you don't want to use git, Github let's you download manually here: https://github.com/Guemache/StatisticsSquad/archive/master.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse + EGit: clone project into workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396349/eclipse-egit-clone-project-into-workspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the repository to your computer with Git (if you do not have install it)

```
git clone https://github.com/Guemache/StatisticsSquad.git
```

In your Eclipse, install the Scala IDE plugin. This project is a "Play Framework"-project so read [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/ide) article to configure your IDE and "eclipsify" your project in order to be able to open it with Eclipse.