# EGit wants to archive Eclipse project data and other inappropriate files

Tags: eclipse, git

OK, I admit that I must have screwed up when I started using EGit.  I started using Eclipse Galileo as a welcome alternative to Notepad edit and command-line compilation.  Somewhat later I discovered that Git was integrated into Eclipse, and happily started using it.

I do not remember all the details, but it seems that I made an initial mistake that has been carried on from one computer to another and one Eclipse upgrade to another.

I have consistently tried to specify that source files are in project subdirectory src and their products are in project subdirectory bin.  Git wants to archive anything in bin, as well as project metadata at the same directory level.

In the past I have been so mono-focused on the project that I just sprinkled gitignore files everywhere and clicked on "Ignore" when preparing a commit.  But now that the project has been brought to a dead halt due to problems in Eclipse Kepler I have resolved to try to disentangle the mess while upgrading to Eclipse Luna.

As I see it, there are three alternatives:  (1) Figure out a way to separate the various directories, (2) Brute force copy-and-paste the 300 some-odd source files into a new, clean directory structure (complicated by the fact that there are currently four open Git branches and several uncommitted changes) or (3) copy the current mess and continue to deal with extraneous "changed" files.

Alternative number one is of course the most desired.

Any suggestions?

(Later)

Please be patient with me.  I am a newby in this venue.  But quite experienced in other venues, where I learned to search for similar questions before posting.

I did try to search for similar problems, to no avail.  I also noticed that, while composing my question, there appeared a list of other questions that might be related.  None seemed applicable, so I ignored it.  When I came back to see if there were any answers, there was the list again and this time I found [Eclipse + EGit: clone project into workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396349/eclipse-egit-clone-project-into-workspace?rq=1).  Perhaps it was there at the top of the list when I finished composing.  I'll know to look next time.

I tried the first recommendation, cloning via EGit from the current location to a new one.  It seemed to work okay, but there are a couple of things missing:  Only the specified branch is available (not MASTER) and the extensive history for the last three years is reduced to one entry dated at the time of cloning.

Fortunately, the other three branches (including MASTER) are not currently divergent.  If necessary, I can manually create them again - if there is some way to recover or display the complete history in the clone.

I was not surprised to see that the several unstaged changes in the source were not present.  I can deal with those manually, but I wonder if it would help if I staged them before my next attempt to clone?

(Staging those changes may or may not be possible.  I became very frustrated with problems using Eclipse Kepler and gave up trying to do anything more to resolve the problems several months ago.  I did not document the problems, and by now have forgotten what they were.  I have a vague memory of trying to commit current changes and running into fatal errors.)

Now I think I have a more focused question - or rather several questions:

(1) When upgrading Eclipse to a new version, is EGit cloning the easiest way to continue an existing project on the same disk?  Should I just copy the original directory?  Should I first clone to GitHub and then clone back to the disk from there?

(2) Should I attempt to stage the uncommitted changes before cloning?

(3) Why is Git history reduced to one entry?  Would it help if I let MASTER be the default branch and then what?  Check out the current (rather lengthy) branch?  Or something else?

(4) What should I do about .project, .settings and other configuration files?  Is it okay to copy them into the new directory structure in the desired places?  Or should I make note of all settings and reconstruct them in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: Using gitignore won't work on files which have already been versioned.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out pretty quickly.