# N-tier architecture in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, n-tier-architecture

I am a newbie to ASP.NET, so i was trying to understand the basic concept of tier and layer and came to know like tier is physical separation like system and layer is  logical separation DLL and communicates through reference. Layer i understood ,but tier i am really don't know what magic will happen for passing data between systems. Consider my scenario like i have 4 systems so 4 tiers and 4 layers , one system(tier) contain database, sotred procedure etc second system contain DAL, third system contain BAL and fourth system contain Presentation layer.How th communication will happen between systems tiers, if all 4 layers are in same system then we can pass data through project reference but between systems?? what magic to do or we need to create 4 webservice for this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is N-Tier architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312187/what-is-n-tier-architecture)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312187/what-is-n-tier-architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's on a different location you need some sort of serialization to pass data between the tiers. There are tons of techniques to communicate across machine boundaries:

- asmx services
- WCF
- Rest API's
- Remoting
- ServiceBus
- Queues
- ...

But yes, the idea is that you abstract the communication and then serialize and deserialize the data before they enter your layers.

Comment: Is it an issue if all the layers are on a single system? Is the solution not meant to be scalable?